# Why is a simple LINQ query much slower than the equivalent SQL query?

Tags: sql, linq

I have to optimize some back-end API calls that use LINQ. So I installed LINQPad and ran some simple test queries. This SQL statement:

```
select * from aspnetusers
```

takes 0.45 seconds to run in LINQPad. This LINQ:

```
from a in AspNetUsers select a
```

takes 6.4 seconds to run.

Would you expect the LINQ to take that much longer? If not, how can I determine the prolem?

**Edit:**
Here is what the AspNetUser entity looks like:

```
namespace myns.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    public partial class AspNetUser
    {
        public AspNetUser()
        {
            //instantiate 5 hashsets here
            //that have to do with other tables
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        //about 40 more similar members here
    }
}
```

Here is what the generated SQL looks like:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    ...50 similar lines here... 
    [Extent1].[TabletNumber] AS [TabletNumber], 
    [Extent1].[TabletId1] AS [TabletId1], 
    [Extent1].[TabletId2] AS [TabletId2], 
    [Extent1].[TabletId3] AS [TabletId3], 
    [Extent1].[TabletId4] AS [TabletId4], 
    [Extent1].[TabletId5] AS [TabletId5]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
```

Also, the primary keys are guid strings that have this format:

`019b9883-5c7d-441b-ad32-674f0bbf1bdd`

Comment: Have you hooked up a sql profile to see what it is actually running against the DB?  Also, are you using Linq to Sql or Entity Framework or other?

Comment: The LINQ query uses EF; I have LINQPad hooked up to my app dll. When I run the LINQ I can see the SQL that is generated. The "generated" SQL is a single select statement with a lot of these: `[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]`.

Comment: There are a number of settings that can help tweak the performance of EF queries.  See [more info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx).  Can you make your question a little more specific by explaining your entities, relationships, and the SQL that was generated?

Comment: See edits to post.

Comment: Run the exact query (including any SET options) in SSMS and see if you can reproduce the issue there. Note that sms returns records before it's finished - you need to wait till it's 'complete' before getting an accurate timing. Also your _true_ generated SQL is whatever you pick up from SQL Profiler. This link http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html is just one example of the often observed trait of LINQ taking longer, although I doubt if it is your issue since you're just selecting from one table.